# Replays - Switch YouTube account that movies are uploaded to?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have recently (and finally!) been able to save takes of replays as movies. I'd like to upload them to my YouTube channel, but I'd also like to track them in Team Fortress 2, especially for the Replay Achievements, as well as be able to have them on my "main" account.

The first time I tried to uploaded a movie, I accidentally logged in to the YouTube account that is directly linked to my Gmail. The one I would like to upload to is a Google+ page which is managed by my Gmail account, does not use my name, and already has a video uploaded (my "main" account).

My question is, how can I change the account that TF2 uploads movies to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution! For those like me who are curious, you'd go to your Steam profile, select Videos, then Add Videos. There, you can change the YouTube account linked to Steam. i am unsure if this is directly the solution, but when I started Team Fortress 2 again, it let me log in to YouTube, and therefore get into my main account. The video has been uploaded and is linked below.

Take a look if you'd like :)